Calculate Difference between two dates
How to calculate the difference between two dates in Power Automate?
I have used ticks function in Power Automate to calculate the date difference. The ticks function is helpful when it comes to parsing dates. It returns a number corresponding to 100-nanosecond intervals.
Divide the date intervals with (100-nanosecond * # of seconds found in a day) as shown below:

div(sub(ticks(variables('RequiredDate')), ticks(variables('currentDate'))), 864000000000)


Did you look into dateDifference?

Yes, we can use that as well. But this gives you the difference in no. of days whereas dateDifference gives in days.hours.minutes.seconds format.

If your code does what you want, what are you asking here?  (And it is pretty easy to isolate the days part from what dateDifference returns.)

I know of two methods that will return the time value differences between two datetime values. The dateDifference() expression is a good method that will return a string that is easier to read and understand. However, this result is not as helpful if the time difference is needed in other steps to be added or calculated.

The use of the ticks() expression can seem complicated at first, but it is really just a way to get datetimes into a factor that can be calculated. When finding the difference between datetimes using the ticks() expression, the output will be a total time value that is either days, hours, minutes, or seconds as an integer. This value is easier to use in other steps where the time might need to be added or calculated with another value.

Then.  What.  Is.  Your.  Question?

Actually, I have posted this question as an alternate answer for reference

And you don't see why an alternate ANSWER does not qualify as a QUESTION?
